# How to get Activity and Context in Flutter plugin

Tags: android, flutter, dart

One of my package need to access `Context` and I got it from `onAttachedToEngine` -> `flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext()` to a variable but this crash the app with `NullPointerException`. The reason is I think I am trying to use the `Context` before it is assigning to the variable.

What is the correct way to access the `Context`?

And how can I get the `Activity` if I wanted too?

Answer (score 61):

Depends on flutter document in [Create-Flutter-Plugin](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Create-Flutter-Plugin), Follow these steps:

1- Import ActivityAware:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityAware
```

2- implement ActivityAware in your class:

```
public class ClassName: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
```

3- Define *lateinit* variables to use it class:

```
private lateinit var context: Context
private lateinit var activity: Activity
```

4- Add these functions:

```
override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    activity = binding.activity;
}

override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

5- Add this line in onAttachedToEngine function:

```
context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
```

You can see this full code for more understanding:

```
package com.example.flutter_plugin_name

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityAware
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityPluginBinding
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar


public class FlutterPluginName: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
  /// The MethodChannel that will the communication between Flutter and native Android
  ///
  /// This local reference serves to register the plugin with the Flutter Engine and unregister it
  /// when the Flutter Engine is detached from the Activity
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var activity: Activity

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "flutter_plugin_name")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
  }



  // This static function is optional and equivalent to onAttachedToEngine. It supports the old
  // pre-Flutter-1.12 Android projects. You are encouraged to continue supporting
  // plugin registration via this function while apps migrate to use the new Android APIs
  // post-flutter-1.12 via https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration.
  //
  // It is encouraged to share logic between onAttachedToEngine and registerWith to keep
  // them functionally equivalent. Only one of onAttachedToEngine or registerWith will be called
  // depending on the user's project. onAttachedToEngine or registerWith must both be defined
  // in the same class.
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
      val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "flutter_plugin_name")
      channel.setMethodCallHandler(FlutterMapboxTurnByTurnPlugin())
    }
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
    }

    else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activity = binding.activity;
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: activity = binding.activity; should be activity = binding.getActivity(); Else code works great for me! Big tnx!

Comment: In Kotlin (which is what language this answer is in), `binding.activity` and `binding.getActivity()` are the same. As long as there are no arguments, any getter can be replaced with a field access.

Comment: Do you know if its mandatory to have FlutterActivity, because I'm using FlutterFragment in a normal Android Activity but the interface methods are not being triggered

Answer (score 15):

Looking at [`BatteryPlugin`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/battery/battery/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/battery/BatteryPlugin.java) source code (Since it is from Flutter team, I think this is the correct way):

```
  private Context mContext; // Instance variable for context

  // ....

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
    onAttach(flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext(),flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger());  // <- this is the line we need here, a new method call
    final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "com.myplugin/my_plugin");
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(new MyPlugin());
  }

 //here is the implementation of that new method
 private void onAttachedToEngine(Context applicationContext, BinaryMessenger messenger) {
     this.mContext = applicationContext;
     methodChannel = new MethodChannel(messenger, "com.myplugin/my_plugin");
     methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
 }

 // ....
```

And here is how [Google Software Engineer from Flutter team recommend to use `Activity`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10769#issuecomment-309098062):

On a simple `MethodChannel` with a annonymous `MethodCallHandler`:

```
public class MyPlugin {
  public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "my_channel");
    final Activity activity = registrar.activity();
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(new MethodCallHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
        // use activity here
      }
    });
  }
}
```

By implementing your class with `MethodCallHandler`:

`Registrar` provides when registration time `activity()` accessor. We can use this `Activity` by implementing our plugin constructor and store it in a field for use in the `onMethodCall` method:

```
public class MyPlugin implements MethodCallHandler {
  private final Activity activity;

  public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "my_channel");
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(new MyPlugin(registrar.activity()));
  }

  private MyPlugin(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
    // use activity here
  }
}
```

Comment: This code for me leads to error mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386113/flutter-plugin-constructor-in-class-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types

Comment: New link: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/battery

Answer (score 2):

I use PlatformViewFactory, I can get Activity, Activity's context and Application context from Registrar.

```
class YourPlatformViewFactory(private val registrar: PluginRegistry.Registrar) : PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {
    override fun create(context: Context?, id: Int, args: Any?): PlatformView {
        val activityContext = registrar.activeContext()
        val appContext = registrar.context()
        val activity = registrar.activity()
        return YourPlatformView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Add this abstract class to your project:**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityAware
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityPluginBinding
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference

abstract class ContextAwarePlugin : FlutterPlugin, ActivityAware, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {

    abstract val pluginName: String

    private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel

    protected val activity get() = activityReference.get()
    protected val applicationContext get() =
        contextReference.get() ?: activity?.applicationContext

    private var activityReference = WeakReference<Activity>(null)
    private var contextReference = WeakReference<Context>(null)

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activityReference = WeakReference(binding.activity)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
        activityReference.clear()
    }

    override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activityReference = WeakReference(binding.activity)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
        activityReference.clear()
    }

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, pluginName)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)

        contextReference = WeakReference(flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
    }
}
```

**Use it this way in your plugin:**

```
class MyPlugin: ContextAwarePlugin() {

  override val pluginName: String = "my-plugin"

  override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    applicationContext //Do something
    activity //Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> full example :

```
package com.example.fluttertoast

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityAware
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityPluginBinding
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar

/** FluttertoastPlugin */
class FluttertoastPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel
  private lateinit var activity:Activity
  private lateinit var context: Context

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.flutterEngine.dartExecutor, "fluttertoast")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    this.context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
  }

  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
      val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "fluttertoast")
      channel.setMethodCallHandler(FluttertoastPlugin())
    }
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      Toast.makeText(activity,"Hello!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
  override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {}
  override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    onAttachedToActivity(binding)
  }
  override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    this.activity = binding.activity
  }
  override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {}
}
```