# Android cursor doesn't work on a Flutter plugin with Android embedding v2

Tags: android, flutter, android-contentprovider, android-context, flutter-plugin

I use a plugin to get the absolute path of a file in Android, the helper class is [this one.](https://github.com/selankon/flutter_absolute_path/blob/update-to-androidX/android/src/main/kotlin/com/kasem/flutter_absolute_path/FileDirectory.kt).

The previous link is a fork from a Flutter plugin that return the absolute path of a photo in photo gallery with Flutter embedding V1 and **work properly**. The Uri is `content://media/external/images/media/41`.

And now I'm trying to adapt this to a plugin with Flutter Android embedding V2. The fork is [here](https://github.com/selankon/flutter_file_dialog/tree/return-noncached-absolute-filepath/android/src/main/kotlin/com/kineapps/flutter_file_dialog). As you can see [here](https://github.com/selankon/flutter_file_dialog/blob/return-noncached-absolute-filepath/android/src/main/kotlin/com/kineapps/flutter_file_dialog/FlutterFileDialogPlugin.kt#L149) I call directly the helper with a hardcoded Uri:

```kotlin
FileDirectory.getAbsolutePath(context, Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/41"))
```

And at the helper class, that basically is a copy paste of the other plugin, the program return error on [this](https://github.com/selankon/flutter_file_dialog/blob/return-noncached-absolute-filepath/android/src/main/kotlin/com/kineapps/flutter_file_dialog/FileDirectory.kt#L139) piece of code:

```kotlin
private fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri, selection: String?,
                              selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)

        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(column_index)
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }
```

This code above **work correctly** on the Flutter embedding V1 **but not** on the V2. After some dirty debugging, I get that:

For Flutter plugin with Android embedding V1:

`context` type equals to `io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication`

`cursor!!.moveToFirst()` is TRUE

`cursor!!.getCount()` is 1

For Flutter plugin with Android embedding V2:

`context` type equals to `android.app.Application`

`cursor!!.moveToFirst()` is FALSE

`cursor!!.getCount() is` 0

I supose that the problem is how the plugin get the application context, for the V1 is given by the `Registrar`:

```kotlin
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
            val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "flutter_absolute_path")
            channel.setMethodCallHandler(FlutterAbsolutePathPlugin(registrar.context()))
        }
    }
```

For the V2, instead, is given by the `ActivityAware` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206235/4708664):

```kotlin
    private fun doOnAttachedToEngine(messenger: BinaryMessenger) {
        methodChannel = MethodChannel(messenger, "flutter_file_dialog")
        methodChannel?.setMethodCallHandler(this)
        context = pluginBinding!!.applicationContext
    }
```

Another thing is that If I try to use the plugin with embeddingV1 in my app, I get the following error, so I can't use it.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.altermundi.elrepoio/net.altermundi.elrepoio.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: registrar.context() must not be null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning the code to minimum I got this working. Probably something wrong in the Flutter embeddingv2 plugin, but using [this](https://github.com/selankon/flutter_absolute_path/commit/9c02e05732410a8cf1e21a40dbe590307cd4e778) it work.