# Invoked Flutter plugin methods will not complete when they are using completable futures in Android

Tags: android, dart, flutter-plugin

I'm building an Android exclusive Flutter plugin that will heavily rely on async tasks on its Android side. For this purpose I'm trying to build a simple example that tests such communication with simulated delays using `CompletableFuture`s in Java. I created the project with

```sh
flutter create --org org.example --template=plugin --platforms=android -a java zcspos
```

My example code is just a delayed echo'ing:

**ZcsposPlugin.java**

```java
    private CompletableFuture<Void> waitAsync(int milliseconds) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull final Result result) {
        switch (call.method) {
            case "echo": {
                final String value = call.argument("value");
                this.waitAsync(1000).thenRunAsync(() -> { // wait 1 second
                    Log.d(this.TAG, "Echoing '" + value + "'");
                    result.success(value);
                });
                break;
            }
            default:
                result.notImplemented();
        }
    }
```

**zcspos.dart**

```dart
  static Future<String?> echo(String value) async {
    return await _channel.invokeMethod<String>('echo', <String, dynamic>{'value': value});
  }
```

**main.dart**

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                RawMaterialButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    fillColor: Colors.blue,
                    highlightColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child: Text(
                      "ECHO TEST",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        print(await Zcspos.echo("Echo 1"));
                        print(await Zcspos.echo("Echo 2"));
                        print(await Zcspos.echo("Echo 3"));
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e.toString());
                      }
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The output is only:

```
Echoing 'Echo 1'
```

But it should be:

```
Echoing 'Echo 1'
Echo 1
Echoing 'Echo 2'
Echo 2
Echoing 'Echo 3'
Echo 3
```

I debugged the Android code and it's calling `result.success`, properly:

[image: Debugging result.success in alternative thread on Flutter Android Plugin]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution while writing the question, so it might be useful to someone in the future.

The result should be fulfilled on the main thread, it won't work on a different thread. One possible solution is to [make sure to have access to the Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048704/how-to-get-activity-and-context-in-flutter-plugin) and then you can simply wrap the `result.success` into `runOnUiThread()`:

**Zcspos.java**

```java
public class ZcsposPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
    private Activity activity;
    private MethodChannel channel;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
        this.activity = binding.getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
        this.activity = binding.getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), "zcspos");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> waitAsync(int milliseconds) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull final Result result) {
        switch (call.method) {
            case "echo": {
                final String value = call.argument("value");
                this.waitAsync(1000).thenRunAsync(() -> {
                    this.activity.runOnUiThread(() -> { // <- HERE WE GO
                        Log.d(this.TAG, "Echoing '" + value + "'");
                        result.success(value);
                    });
                });
                break;
            }
            default:
                result.notImplemented();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
        this.activity = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromActivity() {
        this.activity = null;
    }
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works like charm.